# Searching an NSMutableArray of classes

Tags: objective-c

I have my own class defined as below.

```
@interface PersonList : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSNumber *ID;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *FirstName;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *SecondName;
@end
```

I use it like the following method:

```
PersonList *P = [[PersonList alloc]init];
[P setID: ...];
[P setFirstname:...];
[P setSecondname:...];
```

then add it to an array.

```
[PersonListArray addObject:P];
```

What I'm trying to do is search this array for the class where ID = x.

Is it the best way?

```
for(int i = 0; i < PersonListArray.count; i++)
{
    PersonListArray *aPersonListArray = [PersonListArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if(aPersonListArray.ID == x)
    {
         //Do what i want here
         //break;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `NSArray` method that makes things a lot easier and is also very optimized:

`- (NSUInteger)indexOfObjectPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate`

Your code should then look like that:

```
NSInteger personIndex = [PersonListArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(PersonList person, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                              return [person.ID isEqualToNumber:x];
                        }];

  PersonList personList = PersonListArray[personIndex]
```

Two more things:

- you might consider not capitalizing your variables, to follow conventions.
- If you want to compare values of objects in ObjC, use the `equalTo` methods, not the `==` sign which is for comparing pointers

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, a little bit more simple:

```
for(PersonList *AnyPerson in PersonListArray)
{
    if([AnyPerson.ID isEqualToNumber:x])
    {
         //do what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: May I suggest you to use an NSDictionary and use the ID as the key. It will be much much faster than to make an array traversal

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès But OP already has an array of classes and want the best way to iterate through them.

Comment: this is not okay, you shouldn't compare NSNumbers in this way you should use `isEqualToNumber`

Comment: @JulianKról What do you mean? I don't compare any numbers.

Comment: although yes i do have an array of classes, if there is an easier/better way changing wouldnt be difficult

Comment: try to compare numbers which will be doubles in fact:
NSNumber *val1= [NSNumber numberWithDouble:3];
NSNumber *val2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:3];
your way of comparing will fail in this case!

Comment: AnyPerson.ID it is an NSNumber type so yes you compare NSNumbers, moreover you are missing some symbols in your for loop

Comment: @JulianKról Finally got it. But anyway this method doesn't suit OP.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this like this:

```
 for(PersonList *person in PersonListArray){
   if([person.ID isEqualToNumber: x]){
     // do your job, it you want to do it for the first case only
     // use break here or return depends on the case
    }
 }
```

Take a look at the way of comparing values (if you want sth more than equality consider usage of `compare:` method)

BTW It might be valuable for you to take a look on the possibilities of sorting and searching arrays in case of possibilities and performance, [take a look at this](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/collections.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@interface PersonList ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *persons;

@end

@implementation PersonList

-(NSMutableArray *)persons{
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken,^{
    _persons=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
});
return _persons;
}


-(instancetype)initWithIDs:(NSArray *)personIDs FirstNames:(NSArray *)firstNames SecondNames:(NSArray *)secondNames{
if(self=[super init]){
    [personIDs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id personID, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSMutableDictionary *person=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [person setObject:personID forKey:@"ID"];
        [person setObject:[firstNames objectAtIndex:idx] forKey:@"FIRSTNAME"];
        [person setObject:[secondNames objectAtIndex:idx] forKey:@"SECONDNAME"];
        [self.persons addObject:person];
    }];
}
return self;
}
-(NSDictionary *)findPersonByID:(NSString *)personID{
__block NSDictionary *dictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[self.persons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id person, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([[person objectForKey:@"ID"] isEqualToString:personID]) {
        dictionary=person;
        *stop=YES;
    }
}];
return dictionary;
}

@end
```

Comment: By using an array to store your person records you can use block enumeration to search through them. You can use a bool pointer to stop the search when you find a match. Saves having to step through the entire array after a match has already been found.